# Laravel Jetstream/Sanctum API authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-sanctum, laravel-jetstream, sanctum

I have been working with Laravel since version 5.X up to version 8.X but always use it for backend API (never used blade template), and always pair it with VueJS on the front-end using JWT authentication (also never messed with any other authentication method).

Now with Laravel 9 and Vue 3, Im trying to use native Laravel Jetstream that uses SANCTUM and Vue+Inertia JS, and I'm quite lost with the authentication process. with JWT method, once the user succesfully login on the browser, all api request to Laravel will be authenticated using Authoraziation header. but this seems a different case with Sanctum.

After deploying and installing Jetstream and completed all the set-up. I created a user and loggedin with that user details. and I notice few things, there is a default API route

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

when I tried to directly access `my.domain/api/user` I notice it was redirected to `GET /login`

then redirected again to `GET /dashboard`

I then created a test api route using below

```
Route::get('test', function( Request $req) {
    dd( [
        'test' => $req->all(),
        'user' => auth()->user(),
        'request' => $req
    ] );
});
```

and I notice this request is not authenticated even when the cookies is present on the request as Im when I'm alraedy logged-in on the same browser, the `auth()->user()` is null.

I tried adding `auth:sanctum` middleware

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('test', function( Request $req) {
    dd( [
        'test' => $req->all(),
        'user' => auth()->user(),
        'request' => $req
    ] );
});
```

but having sanctum middle behave the same as the `api/user` where if i open `api/test` directly on the browser, it gets redirected to `GET /login` then redirected again to `GET /dashboard` and I'm quite lost at this point. I tried reading the docs and it says I have to do a separate authentication for this that would issue an API token and I was thinking I might better be going back with using JWT auth as it seems a lot easier to deal with.

So my question is; How can I authenticate an API end-point without having to redirect it to `/login` then `/dashboard` if the user is already logged in on my application using default sanctum authentication.

My goal is just to simply create `/api/test` that will be automatically authenticated if user already loggedin on the same browser and return the data I set on its return value and not doing any redirects.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue with laravel8
Jetstream and inertia vue3.

Am looking for the solution since 3 days posting messages on discord, searching on YouTube and more but nothing.

When i make an api call from your SPA to laravel, i got UNAUTHENTICATED response.

Comment: Did you a find a solution? I am having the same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

on postman you need put

headers
Accept = application/json

this tells your application know how works with Json
and go stop redirect to "Login"